# HSQL configuration in Weblogic

Tags: hsqldb, weblogic9.x

i am completely new to weblogic and hsql so if the question seems trivial please bear with me, so here's my question.
I have application that uses hsql for backend, the problem is that i am not able to configure hsql for weblogic, whenever i Test Configuration its shows

- Connection test failed.
- Cannot load driver: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver

I know it requires hsqldb.jar and i have put it in C:\bea\weblogic92\server\lib, i have used this site for reference http://docs.jboss.org/seam/snapshot/en-US/html/weblogic.html go to "39.2.2.1. Setting up the hsql datasource" here it says "Copy hsqldb.jar to the Weblogic domain's shared library directory: cp $SEAM_HOME/lib/hsqldb.jar $BEA_HOME/user_projects/domains/seam_examples/lib" i am not able to understand this also.

Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are two things to check.

1. Make sure the HSQLDB Jar is the version you need (2.x).
2. Which directory to put hsqldb.jar. This directory is either the general jar lib directory where all the jars used by the system are stored, or it is the jar lib directory for your application. The example for seam is for the second type.

Comment: thanks, i got what my problem was i wasn't putting my hsqldb.jar in right place in weblogic so it was not able to pick up.